# Unable to query graphql in Delivery API playground

Tags: xm-cloud

I am trying to use Graphql playground using the Delivery API endpoint and I am getting an error

```
{
  "error": "Unexpected end of JSON input"
}
```

I am using Edge token as an API key.

[image]

Can anyone guide me?

Additionally, I have set `Sitecore_GraphQL_ExposePlayground="true"` in the XM cloud variable tab

Comment: it seems that the JSON input is incomplete or malformed. Please verify it firstly.

Comment: I have verified it, JSON Input is complete

Answer (score 2):

Once you’ve generated your token, you need to pass your API Token in the headers for your request. If you look at the bottom of the page you will see a `HTTP HEADERS` button that will give you a pane used to add those to your request. You add them in the following format,

```
{
   "X-GQL-Token": "XXX_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE_XXX"
}
```

Once this has been added you will be able to query your data and see results returned.

Reference:

https://robearlam.com/blog/how-to-set-the-experience-edge-auth-token-with-apollo-graphql

https://konabos.com/blog/querying-sitecore-experience-edge-using-the-graphql-endpoint

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your url is wrong in your ide. You are trying to query the IDE and not the API. Change the URL to :

```
https://edge.sitecorecloud.io/api/graphql/v1
```

Change it here: [image]

Comment: Thanks , This resolved the issue

Comment: If this resolved the issue, can you please mark the answer as accepted so others can benefit too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your edge token is valid. Pay attention to the `expires_in` property of the response because JWTs typically expire in 24 hours. After that time, the token is invalid, and you must request a new token.

I would say to create a new token from Edge and add this to your HTTP Headers.

```
{
"sc_apikey":"TOKEN HERE"
}
```

See if this resolves the issue.

Hope it helps.